# Definition of "handle" regarding DLLs

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

Lately I've been fooling around importing functions from DLLs into my C# projects, having lots of fun.

Troubleshooting errors I often stumble on explanations containing: "DDL or handle", "handles of DLLs" and so on.
I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what people mean by "handles".

I'm trying to read different articles anyway to get it by context, but no success there either.

A brief explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article for ["Handle (computing)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)):

> *a handle is an abstract reference to a resource.*

That's basically all there is to it. With the Windows operating system (and others), if you for instance open a file, lots of internal data structures might get allocated (such as the current file pointer, a link to the file system nodes, pre-fetched data buffers, etc.), but you never get direct access to these; all you will get back from the API (e.g. `CreateFile`) is a handle — usually an opaque integer number. "Opaque" here means that this integer number does not have any meaning *to you*, except that you can hand it back to the operating system API functions to identify the associated file.

You can imagine that the operating system keeps an internal mapping table where each handle (integer number) is associated with the corresponding internal resources and data structures. So, using the handle, the OS can make the link to its internal, invisible book keeping structures.

"Closing" or "releasing" a handle means that you tell the OS that the resource associated with a handle (integer value) is no longer needed, and that the OS can release all its internal data structures associated with it (including the handle!).

C and the POSIX libary functions have something quite similar: When you `open` files, you get back an `int`; or from `fopen`, you get back a `FILE*`. Both are really opaque values that you can do nothing with except use them for further system calls. Conceptually it's the same thing as a "file handle".

Handles are usually named after the resources the represent; e.g. a "file handle" is a reference to a file, a "mutex handle" is a reference to a mutex, a "DLL handle" is a reference to a DLL loaded into a process' address space; etc.

Answer (score 0):

A DLL handle like may other handle types in Windows is an opaque object returned by various WIN32 API calls.

The `HANDLE` (defined in a C language header) is a `void*` which doesn't mean much.

Internally The OS stores metadata associated with the DLL and the handle is the key to find it.

It might as well be an index to some array or hash table.

Microsoft can change what goes behind the scenes and the programs will not be affected. E.g. a HANDLE in Windows 7 can be an integer and in Windows 8 it can be an address of a container of some sort.